# как передать viewModelScope в виде зависимости в Koin? у меня есть viewModel и его scope нужно передать как зависимость в другой класс

Tags: android, android-room, koin

в Room Database мне нужно передать СoroutineScope чтоб тот запустил RoomDatabaseCallback( для инициализации базы).

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = 1)
abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

  companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
    ): WordRoomDatabase {
        // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
        // if it is, then create the database
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "word_database"
            )
                    // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                    // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            // return instance
            instance
        }
    }

    private class WordDatabaseCallback(
            private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        /**
         * Override the onOpen method to populate the database.
         * For this sample, we clear the database every time it is created or opened.
         */
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            // If you want to keep the data through app restarts,
            // comment out the following line.
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Populate the database in a new coroutine.
     * If you want to start with more words, just add them.
     */
    suspend fun populateDatabase(wordDao: WordDao) {
        // Start the app with a clean database every time.
        // Not needed if you only populate on creation.
        wordDao.deleteAll()

        var word = Word("Hello")
        wordDao.insert(word)
        word = Word("World!")
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
  }
}
```

`scope: CoroutineScope` мне нужно передать как зависимость

```
val appModule = module {
single <Dao>{ WordRoomDatabase.getInstance(get(),**зависимость сюда Mymodel**).wordDao()}
single<Repository> { RepositoryImpl(get()) }
viewModel { MyModel(get(),get()) }
```

}

на всякий случай этот же вопрос на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183476/koin-pass-coroutinescope-as-dependency-for-roomdatabasecallback

Comment: ссылка не рабочая. И вы наверное имеете ввиду: lifecycleowner - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: исправил ссылка теперт работает